# Making my outdoor light safe overnight

Tags: replacement

[image]

I’ve removed the casing that protects the globe, to replace the globe for the outdoor light. I can’t put the case back on.

My question is, do I take precautions to protect the globe overnight?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you mean by "globe" and "case"; would you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @DanielGriscom "globe" = "bulb".

Comment: OK, why can't you put the casing back on? Is the globe/bulb too big to fit inside?

Comment: If the globe is two small because of the length of the cfl there is not much you can do but put a shorter bulb in or leave it exposed until you find a longer globe to protect the lamp.

Comment: I have a few lights in the same situation ; they have worked well for years. I keep forgetting to buy smaller bulbs.

Answer (score 2):

#### Replace the Fixture

I know that isn't what you want to hear. I had a fixture sort of like this (actually a 2-bulb fixture). Bulbs burnt out frequently due to vibration (door right below). I replaced it with a fluorescent fixture (different type of bulb - i.e., not Edison base). A few years later when that burnt out, I replaced with an LED fixture (integrated LEDs, not a "bulb").

The cost is a more than a bulb, but you:

- Avoid vibration issues affecting the bulb/socket.
- Can get (typically) more light than with an enclosed "ordinary" LED bulb because instead of having to get a bulb that fits the maximum rating for an enclosed fixture, you get a fixture *designed* to produce the desired amount of light.
- Save energy compared to fluorescent (though admittedly LED bulbs would provide similar savings).

Replacement should be straightforward, as long as the existing fixture was mounted correctly on a junction box and not just screwed to the wall around a big hole.

Comment: I have replaced some metal halide with corn row Edison lamps with super success. Ended up with more visible lumens , less power consumption and I hope longer life. theses  are on cat walks that have a fair amount of vibration in a lumber mill, yes they are more expensive but if they last even 1/2 there expected life they will save many times there original cost.+

Answer (score 1):

### Remove it temporarily

Take the "bulb" (light-emitting part) right off of there and keep it in the house for tonight.  Either do without the light, or substitute a cheap, small incandescent.

### This looks like trouble, though

If you're swapping the outer glass casing because the "bulb" is too large for it, then rethink this whole deal.  I'm betting the outer glass casing is *fully enclosed*.  If that's the case, this "bulb" won't cool very well, and will tend to overheat and destroy itself.   Even if I'm wrong about that, CFL types perform poorly in a "base up" orientation (the heat from the tube phosphors goes up, since heat does that, and cooks the ballast), *and this problem is even worse in a stovepipe or fully enclosed fixture*.

If you're doing this because you want way more light than an incandescent gives you, this is the wrong approach.  You might ask advice on that.